# Can I use a parallel port as a CUPS input device?

Tags: linux, hardware, devices, cups, parallel-port

I have an old piece of a hardware that does diagnostics on medical equipment. It prints out results over a parallel port. Is there any way to have CUPS accept jobs from a parallel port and redirect them to the default printer?

Essentially I want CUPS to listen to `/dev/lp0` for incoming jobs.

Reading about this problem a bit, would it be possible for me to capture the [PCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) data via the parallel port (`cat /dev/lp0 > out.pcl`) and then convert it to Postscript using [pspc16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684261/use-ghostscript-to-convert-pcl-to-postscript) or somehow send the PCL to Ghostscript to interpret the PCL and dispatch to CUPS?

Comment: Not clear on the question, are you saying the hardware has a parallel port, normally you would connect directly to a printer, but you would like to connect to a different machines parallel port and use the CUPS service on that machine?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to `service station -> lp -> linux box w/ CUPS -> spool to non-lp printer`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with cups. You would have to write a software listening on the parallel port and sending jobs to cups

Comment: I think you need a special cable, parallel ports aren't wired symmetrically (I'm not sure a crossover cable would be enough: some pins aren't wired inside the computer). There are two parts to your problem: getting the data from the diagnostics equipment to your computer's parallel port, for which you'll find more expertise on [su], and routing the data from the parallel port to CUPS, which this site should address best.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with a PC alone the parallel port is not designed to act as a printer.

You will need some sort of hardware that emulates a printer and then relays the data to the computer.

[This page](http://www.pclviewer.com/resources/capture/) describes the sort of product you need.  I don't know anything about that specific company.

Another option option might be a [parallel to serial converter](http://www.bb-elec.com/product.asp?sku=232SPS2) and then connect that to your PC.

Comment: Why can't the PC do this in software? There has to be some kind of project that tackled this, the technology is like 40 years old.

I mean, you're telling me if I want to turn a Linux box into an LPT printer, I'm SOL? This sounds like a popular request.

Comment: Very specific need. Legacy hardware support.

Comment: I am pretty sure you could do it manually yourself. Just write a software reading the data from the parallel port and process it.

Comment: If you have a parallel port hardware that you could control all of the pins (i.e. read and write to/from all of them). It might be possible to write your own device driver that can emulate a parallel printer.  There are some pins that are in normal operation only outputs from the PC and I don't know if the hardware in a PC would allow you to use them as inputs.

Comment: Even if that was case, perhaps I just need to hack together a custom driver and a cross-over. Though I highly doubt this problem needs to be this complex.

Comment: An adequate cable and some userspace software to read the data from the parallel port should be all you need. You might need to hack your own software, though.

Comment: For the cable, see [Laplink (null-printer) cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable). For the software... I don't know but you will probably be operating on `/dev/parport*` (the raw parallel port device) instead of `/dev/lp*` (specifically made for *talking to* a printer, not pretending to be one)

Comment: The problem is that a classic parallel port (computer end) has 12 outputs (8 data lines + 4 for various signaling purposes) but only 5 inputs, so it isn't trivially reversible. LapLink uses only 5 of the data lines, a specially wired cable and a custom signaling which is not usually supported by printers. Modern parallel ports with EPP/ECP capability can be fully bi-directional, but the bi-directional modes work differently from the standard uni-directional mode, so making a computer simulate a classic parallel printer is non-trivial.